# Does Apache Beam Elastic IO module support updates to existing documents by Id?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I could not find any  documentation for  updates of documents on elastic search with apache beam.
Does apache beam support updates for elastic search?

Answer (score 1):

With `Beam` `Java`, you can use [ElasticsearchIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchIO.html).

Example to write a `PCollection` to `ElasticSearch` :

```java
pipeline
    .apply(...)
    .apply(ElasticsearchIO.write().withConnectionConfiguration(
       ElasticsearchIO.ConnectionConfiguration.create("http://host:9200", "my-index", "my-type")
    )
```

Important clarification, the IO does not support `update` type operations, the `write` method allows **adding** an element in `Elastic`.

If it's mandatory for you to apply update operations, you have 3 solutions :

- Use the write and existing IO with duplicates, and in a separated process outise of Beam, remove duplicate and keep only the last element in `Elastic`. For example you can use a `DAG` orchestrator and execute a service after the `Dataflow` job
- Use an existing `Elastic` `client` with `update` method and use it in a `ParDo`
- Develop your own IO based on an existing client with the update method

This IO doesn't exists natively for `Beam` `Python`.

You can check this [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/) to have the list of existing IO in `Beam`.